# Is there a way of renaming columns automatically in power query after a refresh

Tags: powerquery, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list that is connected to Excel.
[List in SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jE7k.png)

In that list there are dates entered in the columns header.
After importing that list from SharePoint to Excel, the string "ODATA_" is placed before the dates in the column header.
[Table in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0c6E.png)

I know I can manually edit the column before importing it in Excel, but how can this be done automatically after the connections is refreshed?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the column names (headers) or the column values?

Comment: Column names (headers)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide some screenshots